# The wrong data is being copied into another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am copying some data from two columns A and B based on if there is the word `PRNA` in B then I copy A and B into "Sheet1". The problem now I am facing is that it copies everything that has `PRNA` but sometimes it copies `Not available` as well.  This is the code:

```
 Dim Cell2 As Range, LastRow2 As Long
    Dim count As Integer

    LastRow2 = Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng3 = Range("B2:B" & LastRow2)
     Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each Cell2 In rng3

        If Cell2.Value = "PRNA" Then
            'Range(Cells(rng3.Row, 1), Cells(rng3.Row, 2)).Copy

            'Range("A1").Offset(count, 0).PasteSpecial

            Range(Cells(Cell2.Row, 1), Cells(Cell2.Row, 2)).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A1").Offset(count, 0)
            count = count + 1

        End If

    Next Cell2
```

So I am copying only `PRNA` and the cell A next to Cell B which has `PRNA`.

[image]

And this is the output:

[image]

I don't know what the issue here is..maybe it loops too fast?

Comment: It is hard to tell what is going wrong with what you have posted, my guess is you need to qualify your range and cell references.  Because you have more than one sheet involved you should always put the parent object in front of your range and cells.

Comment: I have now added the initialization of the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
Sub copyPRNA()
Dim ows As Worksheet
Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
Dim cnt As Long

Set ows = ActiveSheet
Set tws = Sheets("Sheet1")

Set rng = ows.Range(ows.Range("B2"), ows.Range("B" & ows.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each cell2 In rng
    If cell2 = "PRNA" Then
        tws.Range("A" & tws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 2).Value = ows.Range(cell2.Offset(, -1), cell2).Value
    End If
Next cell2

End Sub
```

Always when working with range and cells, qualify the parent.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this: you are probably copying formulas, this will just copy values.

```
    Sub CopyStuff()
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
Set rng3 = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B10")
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim rng As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each cell2 In rng3
    If UCase(cell2.Value) = UCase("PRNA") Then
        Set rng = cell2.Offset(0, -1)
        ws.Range(rng.Address).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(rng.Value, cell2.Value)
    End If
Next cell2
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, 

Your code works perfectly fine but it copies in the cell address of the Sheet ISIn. So if PRNA was in cell A1100 it would copy in sheet 2 in cell A1100. How would I amend this so it copies without these big spaces in between just row by row ?

Comment: yes, I would use something like ws.Cells(rows,count,2).end(xlup).row+1